# Adding unique ID column associated to two groups R

Tags: r, grouping, columnsorting, group

I have a data frame in this format:

| Group | Observation |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 2 |
| a | 3 |
| b | 4 |
| b | 5 |
| c | 6 |
| c | 7 |
| c | 8 |

I want to create a unique ID column which considers both group and each unique observation within it, so that it is formatted like so:

| Group | Observation | Unique_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1.1 |
| a | 2 | 1.2 |
| a | 3 | 1.3 |
| b | 4 | 2.1 |
| b | 5 | 2.2 |
| c | 6 | 3.1 |
| c | 7 | 3.2 |
| c | 8 | 3.3 |

Does anyone know of any syntax or functions to accomplish this? The formatting does not need to exactly match '1.1' as long as it signifies group and each unique observation within it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way using `cur_group_id` and `row_number`

```
library(dplyr)

A <- 'Group Observation
a   1
a   2
a   3
b   4
b   5
c   6
c   7
c   8'

df <- read.table(textConnection(A), header = TRUE)
```

```
df |> 
  group_by(Group) |> 
  mutate(Unique_ID = paste0(cur_group_id(), ".", row_number())) |> 
  ungroup()

  Group Observation Unique_ID
  <chr>       <int> <chr>    
1 a               1 1.1      
2 a               2 1.2      
3 a               3 1.3      
4 b               4 2.1      
5 b               5 2.2      
6 c               6 3.1      
7 c               7 3.2      
8 c               8 3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("Group Observation
a   1
a   2
a   3
b   4
b   5
c   6
c   7
c   8")

df %>%
  mutate(unique = Group %>%
           as.factor() %>%
           as.integer() %>% 
           paste(., Observation, sep = "."))

#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   Group Observation unique
#>   <chr>       <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1 a               1 1.1   
#> 2 a               2 1.2   
#> 3 a               3 1.3   
#> 4 b               4 2.4   
#> 5 b               5 2.5   
#> 6 c               6 3.6   
#> 7 c               7 3.7   
#> 8 c               8 3.8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df |> group_by(Group) |>
mutate(Unique_ID = paste0(cur_group_id(),".",1:n()))
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
# Groups:   Group [3]
  Group Observation Unique_ID
  <chr>       <int> <chr>    
1 a               1 1.1      
2 a               2 1.2      
3 a               3 1.3      
4 b               4 2.1      
5 b               5 2.2      
6 c               6 3.1      
7 c               7 3.2      
8 c               8 3.3
```